How to think of regular orbits of a finite orthogonal group?
Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $O(n)$ acting on $\mathbb R^n$. A regular orbit of the action is one such that the cardinality of the orbit is equal to $|G|$.
I am at a loss as to how to prove some seemingly simple things about regular orbits. For example, why is the set of regular orbits dense in the quotient space $\mathbb R^n/G$? This boils down to asking what the fixed points of orthogonal transformations are, but I don't know how to approach this question.
Also, why are the regular orbits smooth points in the quotient space $\mathbb R^n/G$?

If $g\in O(n)$ is an orthogonal transformation ( and $g \not = Id$), its set of fixed points is a vector space of codimension at least one.
There fore the set $\Omega= \{x \forall g\in G, g x\not=x \}$ is an open dense subset.
On this dense set $G$ acts freely and isometrically, so that $\Omega / G$ is a smooth manifold the finite group

Why is the set of fixed points of an orthogonal transformation a vector space of codimension at least $1$?

Also, I know that a free and properly discontinuous group action implies that the quotient is smooth. Is it trivial to see that an isometric action is properly discontinuous?


It can be one : think of a reflexion $(x,y)\to (-x,y)$. 2. let $x$ in this set and $d$ its distnace to the complementary . 2. The ball $B(x,d/4)$ is disjoint t o all its $g$ translates, as the distance is invariant.


In the 2d case it's simple to see that the fixed points form a space of codimension at least $1$, because you only have to prove it for reflections and rotations, and reflections are around an axis, so only that axis is fixed. But how do you prove it in general, for $O(n)$? I have no clue what transformations in $O(n)$ generally look like...

For every linear transformation the set $l(x)=x$ is a vector subspace, so of codimension $\geq 1$ if $l$ is not the identity. For the point 2. My argument is wrong, replace it by the ball $B(x, d/4)$ where $d$is the minimum of the distances $d(x,gx)$ with $g\not= id$. By the triangular inequality $B(x,d/4) \bigcap g.B(x,d/4)=B(gx,d/4) $ is empty.
